# What does "<>" mean in haskell sample code?

Tags: haskell, operator-keyword

I have done lots of googling and failed in figuring this question out. Partially because google does not treat "<>" as a keyword. I see this "operator" from the code sample at [optparse-applicative sample](https://github.com/pcapriotti/optparse-applicative)

Anybody knows the meaning of "<>" in haskell please help. Thanks!

Comment: Unclarified uses of `<>` are almost certainly [`<>` from Data.Monoid](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:-60--62-), which is an infix alias for [`mappend`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:mappend).

Comment: I like [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=%3C%3E) for searching Haskell APIs.

Comment: Hayoo and/or Hoogle is your friend.

Answer (score 7):

Like Alexis said in the comment above, `(<>)` is from Data.Monoid. You can think of monoids as appendable things, so lists and text and stuff like that, and `<>` or `mappend` is how you append them. `[1,2,3] <> [4,5,6]` is the same as `[1,2,3] ++ [4,5,6]` -- both resulting in `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

In the library you linked to, `ParserHelp` is defined as a monoid [here](https://github.com/pcapriotti/optparse-applicative/blob/cc7faf83cac327f7c33bf368ee22cb64a42d44aa/Options/Applicative/Help/Types.hs#L24) so you can use `<>` to "add" `ParserHelp`s.

Googling operators is tough. [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is really helpful for this!